# Getting WINS Server Statistics

Tags: scripting, windows, wins

I know WINS is ancient. No need to remind me. For what it's worth, this effort is going toward a project to retire it from the environment altogether.

But before I can do that - I need to be able to scriptomatically or programmatically gather statistics from it.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

See "Total querries," (lol at the misspelling) "Record found", etc.?

How do I get at those values? They're not in Perfmon, they're not in any WMI class I've found. I can't find any related COM objects. There are counters like "queries/sec," but I don't care about queries/sec. I want total queries. Just like in the screenshot above.

I'll P/Invoke Win32 if I have to... just... where do I get these metrics?

Comment: From my research, there's a JET database that WINS uses...there's a good place to start looking.

Comment: Per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168712 it looks like there's info in the registry and under `C:\Windows\system32\Wins` that might be useful. I didn't post an answer because I don't have WINS ;)

Comment: Are you trying to find clients that may still be using wins?  if so we just looked at the firewall logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found what I was looking for with `netsh wins server show statistics`. I'll have to parse some output text, but at least I can script it.

[image: WINS stats]

Comment: -1 for not explaining things.

Comment: @tonyroth What's there to explain? `netsh wins server show statistics` returns the statistics.

Comment: It is beyond obvious what his solution was, and I can't actually think of a better way to explain it.

Comment: lol no screen shot for me!

Comment: That would do it!

Comment: also the edit cleared things up...